# How to connect to remote LDAP server using foreign JNDI settings in weblogic

Tags: java, weblogic, jndi

I have LDAP server and created foreign LDAP provider in weblogic. I am writing java code to get LDAP server details from foreign LDAP provider.

```
        try 
        {
             InitialContext cctx = null;   
            Properties  envHash = new Properties ();
            envHash.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");

            envHash.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
            envHash.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "weblogic");
            envHash.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "password");
            envHash.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "t3://localhost:7001");  

           cctx = new InitialContext(envHash);

             // Pass the Local JNDi Name here
             Object ctx = cctx.doLookup(new CompositeName().add("OUDJNDIProvider"));
```

But code is failing with below exception. Anyone has example how to get JNDI details from java code?

```
javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file: java.naming.factory.initial at
javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(Unknown Source) at
javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(Unknown Source) at
javax.naming.InitialContext.getURLOrDefaultInitCtx(Unknown Source) at
javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(Unknown Source) at
javax.naming.InitialContext.doLookup(Unknown Source) at
com.company.GetJNDIDetails.main(GetJNDIDetails.java:35)
```

Comment: Stack trace? You got this exception on which line?

Comment: I got this error at this line. Object ctx = cctx.doLookup(new CompositeName().add("OUDJNDIProvider"));

Comment: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
 at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(Unknown Source)
 at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(Unknown Source)
 at javax.naming.InitialContext.getURLOrDefaultInitCtx(Unknown Source)
 at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(Unknown Source)
 at javax.naming.InitialContext.doLookup(Unknown Source)
 at com.wiley.GetJNDIDetails.main(GetJNDIDetails.java:35)